# Java- how to temporarily store data in array-list

Tags: java

i want to cache arrlist values to be available in a class, i am define an empty arrlist instially and adding values on it from a method and then finally trying to get that global defined arralist values....

```
class Test{ 

    ArrayList list=new ArrayList();


    public void addValues(){

        list.add("One");
        list.add("Two");
        list.add("Three");
        list.add("Four");
        list.add("Five"); 
        getArrlstValues();
    }

    public void getArrlstValues(){

        System.out.println("size of cache arralist=" +list.size());
        //why this is showing zero size
    }

     public static void main(String args[]) {
     Test obj=new Test();
     obj.addValues();
 }
}
```

Comment: I don't even see a question mark in your post.

Comment: Do you know that the `ArrayList` values are cached in your code.

Comment: You populate `list` of object 1 and get the list of object 2, why should object 2 reflect changes on object 1?

Comment: @Salah its not cached,its showing size of arrylist zero at the getarrylistvaues method... i mention in my question

Comment: remove the Test obj. Cust call getArrlstValues() without "obj." infront. You are creating 2 different objects with a list in each one. Also you should use probably use private access modifiers and Generic type in your list.

Comment: @TheLostMind i have mention the answer of your question at the end of my question. plz check

Comment: Just call `getArrlstValues();`, not `obj.getArrlstValues();`.

Comment: why -ve vote, why you are not writing comment, as i read the so rules,  we have to write comment on -ve vote!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how is this even working in the first place if every `Test` object references another `Test` object as `obj`?

Comment: Actually downvoters are under no obligation to post comments when they vote (just as upvoters aren't either). It's purely a suggestion that they do. Voting is *intended* to be anonymous, and that is not likely to change.

Comment: @JonK - I disagree. Commenting on a DownVote is far more important than commenting on an Upvote. Comment could tell you what is wrong / expected.

Comment: There's nothing to disagree with, downvoters **are not obliged to comment**. [It has been](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260007/please-associate-downvotes-with-reasons) [discussed to death](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250177/require-an-explanation-reason-for-the-first-downvote-on-a-question) [on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253531/enable-optional-anonymous-reasons-for-downvotes-on-questions).

Comment: @Jasper sorry, i copied wrong question, i updated it , please take a look

Comment: Do you mind copying and pasting your main method here?

Comment: @fajarkoe updated my question, still i have not get answer for what i am looking for, so many people is saying something else none have understand my problem...

Comment: @Sundara Thanks. One more question, how does the method getArrlstValues() get invoked? I don't see any code that invoke it.

Comment: @Sundara I have just ran your code. It prints 5 -- not 0. May be you want to try it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you add values to `this.list` and check `obj.getArrlstValues()`, when **this != obj**.

So you never update the same list you look at!

You can use `this.getArrlstValues()`  (or just `getArrlstValues()`) and remove this line:

```
Test obj=new Test()
```

Comment: so what should i do to update and get the cached values again?

Comment: Calling getArrlstValues() instead of obj.getArrlstValues()

Comment: I am sorry, the question was wrong, i updated my question, my problem is `System.out.println("size of cache arralist=" +list.size());
        //why this is showing zero size`

Comment: @Sundara, This question has nothing to do with Caching. Caching is a bigger concept. In this example whenever you trigger main method new List object is created. Nothing is cached here. As Bob pointed out you were setting values in one instance and reading from another instance.

Comment: rightly said there isn't anything cached here, its just a class which has an Arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
    Test obj=new Test()

    public void addValues(){

        list.add("One");     // working on "this" i.e, the current object
        list.add("Two");     // still  working on this
        list.add("Three");
        list.add("Four");
        list.add("Five");
        obj.getArrlstValues();  // calling getArrlstValues() on a different object. Just use getArrlstValues();
    }

    public void getArrlstValues(){

        System.out.println("size of cache arralist=" +list.size()); 
        //why this is showing zero size --> because for the calling Object i.e, obj, the list is empty
    }
```